# Editing orders dont work 2.0.1.1 or sales order not deleted on OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Trying to delete sales order so it is not working.
When try  to click in update order button not do anything some time give me jose error

Comment: As it is written, your question is too broad. Please include code as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
create a api user form login as admin> system> users> api
but the web site in  maintained mode
Enable  php server enable curl function

if this not solve problem do this:

Step 2:
the problem is caused by your Hosting did disable the 443 port.
The Opencart did use curl_setopt function to retrieve information from severs on ports 443 (for https).
You can try enable the 443 port on server or try edit the file: admin/config
finde code:

```
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://yoursite.com/');
```

change to:

```
//define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://yoursite.com/');
```

=> change "https" to "http"
=> so Opencart will use 80 port(NOT 443)

https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=139436